# Page breaks when updating @all forms

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a simple composition with a menu, and the menu has a *p:selectOneMenu* for the locale

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">
<f:view locale="#{sesion.locale}">
<h:head>
  <title>Hello World JSF 2.3</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/template1.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="contenido">
            <h:form id="content">
                <p:outputLabel value="#{i18n_base['helloworld']}"/>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

The menu

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">
<f:view locale="#{sesion.locale}">
<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="menu">
        <p:menubar>
            <p:submenu label="${i18n_menu['flujos']}">
                <p:menuitem value="${i18n_menu['flujo.edicion']}" url="/frontend/gestion/flujo/lista.xhtml"/>
                <p:menuitem value="${i18n_menu['flujo.creacion']}" url="/frontend/gestion/flujo/edicionFlujo.xhtml"/>
            </p:submenu>

            <f:facet name="options">
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{sesion.locale}" converter="localeConverter">
                    <p:ajax listener="#{sesion.localeCambiado}" update="@form"/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{sesion.allLocales}" var="_locale" itemValue="#{_locale}" itemLabel="${i18n_menu['locale.' += _locale.language]}"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
        </p:menubar>
    </h:form>

    <ui:insert name="contenido">Contenido</ui:insert>
</h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

And I get this page

[image]

With this code it works as expected: When I change the selected language the menu language is updated but the "helloworld" label is not affected.

But if I change the "update" attribute of the "p:ajax" component, when I update the value then the page breaks

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

I am using Primefaces 7.0 on WildFly 18.0.0.1

Comment: Just a note @all can be quirky as you may as ell do a whole NON AJAX refrsh.  I would update only the components you need to update even if you have to wrap them all in a PrimeFAces OutputPanel and update that ID.

Comment: Agree with @Melloware. If you really need to update all the page, don't use an ajax.

Comment: I don't see any `update="@all"` in your code. So I assume you just not posted the non-working code?

Comment: @Kukeltje I have the issue when I change *update="@form"* (in the posted code) by *update="@all"* (no other changes to the code).

Comment: Yep don't do @all you may as well do `ajax='false'` if you are going to do @all.